# Creating a textbox to trigger a VBA formula

Tags: vba, excel, textbox

Recently I created Macros which searched through column B using a text match and populated column H with "Y" or "N" depending on whether there was a match or not. The code used was as follows.

```
    lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    .Range("H2:H" & lRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(C[-6] = ""Commodities Ags/Softs"", " & _
                                        "(IF(RC[-3]=R1C24,""Y"",(IF(RC[-3]=R2C24,""Y""," & _
                                        "(IF(RC[-3]=R3C24,""Y"",(IF(RC[-3]=R4C24,""Y""," & _
                                        "(IF(RC[-3]=R5C24,""Y"",(IF(RC[-3]=R6C24,""Y""," & _
                                        "(IF(RC[-3]=R7C24,""Y"",(IF(RC[-3]=R8C24,""Y""," & _
                                        "(IF(RC[-3]=R9C24,""Y"",""N"")))))))))))))))))),"""")"

               Range("H2:H" & lRow).Select
               Selection.Copy

               ActiveSheet.Range("H2:H" & lRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

I had to write 7 different macros because of the 7 possible matching texts in column B and the data I was matching it to comes from 7 different sources. I.E. If I received data from Commodities Ags/Softs, I would run the Commodities Ags/Softs macro (the other macros are identical, just swapping the text).

Now I've been told the data will be expanding to 70 different sources with 70 potential matching texts, rendering my specific macro to specific data approach pretty useless.

I was wondering if anyone knows how I could generalise the macro and in doing so, create a textbox which would tell the macro what text to match in column B.

Basically, I was hoping that if I received data from a particular source, I could run the macro, a textbox would appear in excel and whatever I typed into it would be the text I'm trying to match in column B, effectively altering the generalised macro.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm new to VBA,

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically:

```
Dim sMatch as String
sMatch = InputBox("Enter match data")
lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With .Range("H2:H" & lRow)
   .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(C[-6] = """ & sMatch & """, " & _
                                    "(IF(RC[-3]=R1C24,""Y"",(IF(RC[-3]=R2C24,""Y""," & _
                                    "(IF(RC[-3]=R3C24,""Y"",(IF(RC[-3]=R4C24,""Y""," & _
                                    "(IF(RC[-3]=R5C24,""Y"",(IF(RC[-3]=R6C24,""Y""," & _
                                    "(IF(RC[-3]=R7C24,""Y"",(IF(RC[-3]=R8C24,""Y""," & _
                                    "(IF(RC[-3]=R9C24,""Y"",""N"")))))))))))))))))),"""")"

    .Value = .Value
End With
```

Comment: That's great but it's not populating column H with "Y" or "N"?